# Latest release not appearing in Xcode Crashes Organizer

Tags: xcode, crash-reports

I released a new version 6 days ago. I see some crashes in iTunesConnect analytics, but none in the crashes organizer, nor does my release even appear in the "version" dropdown within the crashes organizer.

Normally it takes a day or two after a release for crash reports to make their way into the Xcode Crashes organizer, and anecdotally I've seen the crashes appear in the Xcode Crashes organizer about the same time as in the iTunesConnect analytics website.

Interestingly, the previous versions still show in the "version" dropdown and I can see reports continue to trickle in for them. There is a steep decline in crash reports for that previous version, presumably as most folks have moved to the latest version.

On a new machine, with a fresh XCode install (but linked to the same developer account) I see the same behavior. Maybe it's a problem with my developer account?

**Update 2016.09.01**: Two months later, new releases are still not showing up in the releases dropdown automatically. The workaround posted below to manually add them has been working great, but hopefully I don't have to do it forever. I have to assume this is a problem with my local setup as this can't be happening to *everyone*. Let me know if you figure out a long term fix.

**Update 2016.10.13**: The [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336138/353178) isn't working for my most recent release. I again see crashes in ITC, but after manually adding an entry for the release in Info.json, I see "No crash information is available for this release."

**Update 2016.10.15**: I guess the work around is continuing to work, the crash reports were just delayed by an *extra* 48 hours.

**Update 2016.1.20**: At some point, (maybe around mid december, XCode 8.2?), I started to see new releases appear automatically again, and no longer have the joy of manually editing my XCode config data every time I push a build. Other than updating XCode, I can't think of any way I might have "fixed" it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's likely a bug with Xcode/ITC services. I filed a radar (#27277793) yesterday and was on ITC tech support today. If you're having this issue *please* [report it to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) and reference the existing radar (#27277793) so Apple can recognize we're having the same problem and prioritize a fix.

A workaround to get the crash reports for my latest release was to manually add a new entry in the crash organizers Info.json.

In: `$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products/<bundle.id>` edit the Info.json and add a new entry to the beginning of the "productVersions" array based on the existing entries, but change the build number to whatever build the crash reports are for.

You also *must* update the appStoreStatus field depending on whether your app is in TestFlight or in the AppStore. `appStoreStatus: 1` for TestFlight and `appStoreStatus: 3` for AppStore.

After relaunching Xcode and going to the crashes organizer I watched as the last 6 days of crash reports came in.

Yay for human readable configuration data!

Comment: This approach works in the case when no crash reports appear on one setup, but they DO appear on another developer's setup.

Comment: Wow great fix. I encountered this bug with Xcode 8.3.1

Comment: Deleting the folder of crash logs located in $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products/<bundle.id> helped me

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem for ALL my projects. I tried every suggestion but nothing works. Will the new versions and crash logs appear straight away or will it take more time?

Comment: It seems like XCode caches the most recently pulled crash reports for at least a while (minutes? hours?), but IIRC killing XCode after editing the configuration and relaunching the crashes organizer was sufficient. 

There would be a progress spinner for a few seconds, then the new crashes appeared (of course the customary ITC crash reporting delay of 24-48 hours applies, so if there weren't any crashes in the last day or two they might not show up yet).

Comment: this doesn't work for me. after deleting the folder Xcode "downloads" new data but doesn't show any version or crashes :(

Comment: This manual workaround is still necessary for me at end of July 2017. For me, even though appStoreStatus: 1 is set, in xcode the crashes still come out as "app store".

Comment: Does not work for me.  Organizer still says "No crashes" for my current app store version, yet iTunes connect and my email reports show plenty.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue where Xcode crash reports stopped updating after we increased our deployment target iOS version. Fix was to edit Info.json like mentioned above and remove all unsupported OS versions from "supportedOSVersions" array of latest build that was appearing in "productVersions" array.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when none of the above answers did.

Find the Info.json file as described above in mkirk's answer.  Make a copy as a backup.  In the productVersions section remove any unneeded versions. As you can see below, "productVersions" is a json array, and it will contain a series of json objects, each of which represents one of your versions.  I desperately needed crash reports for a recent release to the app store and after deleting *all* versions preceding that (below it) and restarting Xcode, voila! the Organizer suddenly began showing all my crash reports.

```
"productVersions" : [
    {
      "version" : "4.0.45",
      "productType" : 1,
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products/ directory. Quit and restart Xcode and then run Organizer. They all come through after that.

Comment: didn't worked, I see a list with not all the builds.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps,

1. Remove bundle from Xcode products using,

   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products/com.yourapp.bunlde
2. Restart you Xcode and open Organizer
3. Make sure that itunesconnect sites are accessible

Xcode->Organizer is supposed to download all crashlogs from beginning. Hope that helps.

Comment: won't this also delete the DSYMs?

Comment: You can move files to other directory rather remove if you want to keep archives.