# Understanding crash report in iTunes Connect and XCode Organizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-organizer

If I'm understanding the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW3) correctly I should be able to see the crashes in XCode Organizer, but here is my situation.

When I go to iTunes Connect I see crashes in some of the app versions but when I go to XCode Organizer, select the version that in iTunes Connect shows crashes I don't see any crashes, it's empty. I tried clicking the download dSYMs button but nothing happens.

Can someone confirm my assumption that crashes I see in iTunes Connect should be available/visible in XCode Organizer?

Thanks

Comment: This stack overflow answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335631/latest-release-not-appearing-in-xcode-crashes-organizer