# Xcode Organizer issue, Cannot see crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I cannot see crashes in my Organiser -> Crashes though I am seeing 5 crashes on my iTunes connect. Anybody know the reason?

Comment: There is an issue mentioned in the Apple Developer Forum https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81764 also there is a topic with the same question: Latest release not appearing in Xcode Crashes Organizer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335631/latest-release-not-appearing-in-xcode-crashes-organizer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latest release not appearing in Xcode Crashes Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335631/latest-release-not-appearing-in-xcode-crashes-organizer)

Comment: No, It does not answer my question, I can view one crash in the organiser but other crashes are missing.

Comment: I can also view all my builds in the drop down of organiser -> crashes